# Does an efficient algorithm exist to determine the points of intersection between the edges of two possibly non-convex polygons?

Tags: geometry, polygon

Here's the task I'm trying to solve:
Given a polygon A with N vertices and a polygon B with M vertices, find all intersections between a segment in A and a segment in B.
Both A and B may be non-convex.

So far, I have implemented the obvious solution(check every edge in A with every edge in B, O(M*N)).
Now, for certain polygons it is in fact possible that there are (almost) M*N intersections, so the worst case for any such algorithm is O(M*N).

My question is:
Does there exist an algorithm for determining the points of intersection between two non-convex polygons with **complexity in the average case that is lower than O(N*M)**

If yes, then please give me the name of the algorithm, if no - some resource that proves it to be impossible.

Comment: Try checking out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatti_clipping_algorithm and http://sourceforge.net/projects/polyclipping/

Comment: That's one of the places I've looked at. I am trying to implement this, though: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weiler%E2%80%93Atherton

Comment: Also, I just read [the paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.88.3266&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and it seems that they do the same thing as me - O(M*N)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excerpt from a [paper on the Greiner-Hormann (PDF)](http://www.inf.usi.ch/hormann/papers/Greiner.1998.ECO.pdf) polygon clipping algorithm:

> ... if we have a
>   polygon with n edges and another with
>   m edges, the number of intersections
>   can be nm in the worst case. So the
>   average number of intersections grows
>   on the order of O(nm).
>
> There is a
>   well-known result in computational
>   geometry based on the plane sweep
>   algorithm, which says that if there
>   are N line segments generating k
>   intersections, then these
>   intersections can be reported in time
>   O((N+k) log(N)) [7]. Note that this
>   relation yields an even worse
>   complexity in the worst case.

I believe N in the second paragraph is m + n from the first paragraph. The average time depends the average value of k, the number of intersections. If there are only a handful of intersections the time goes to O(N log N).

The reference to the "well-known" result is:

> [7] F. P. Preparata and M. I. Shamos.
>   Computational Geometry: An
>   Introduction. Texts and Monographs in
>   Computer Science. Springer, New York,
>   1985.

Here's a [paper on the line sweep algorithm](http://www.jn.ethz.ch/education/script/P6_C25.pdf).